# Can I use arcpy to change the placement properties of labels?

Tags: label, arcgis

I'm labeling a points feature class using arcpy, but I really need the label to sit on top of the point. Is there any way to do this with arcpy? Or does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access that label property with arcpy, you need ArcObjects. The only workaround I can think of is (not tested):

1. Convert labels to annotations using [Append Annotation Feature Classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002t000000) (requires at least a Standard license)
2. Move annotations by modifying their shape field (centroid of the annotation should be replaced with the corresponding point's XY coords).